# Regular expression to stop special characters except _ in between not in start

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to create a regular exp to  to stop user entering special character at any place int he string but alowing numbers and underscore inside string except at starting point .

scenarios

```
        abhi_3123123  valid
        abhi___ASDFAS valid
        3425_asdfasdf invalid
        _asdfasdf     invalid
        sometext(having any spcl character at any place) invalid
```

only underscore should be allowed only in between not in start and end

updated code

i m calling this code on textchange event of my textbox

```
 string regEx = @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?<!_)$";
 if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtFunctionName.Text, regEx))
 {
   //no error
 }
 else
 {
   // show error
 }
```

this code is showing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to allow ASCII letters, digits and underscore, use

```
^[a-zA-Z]\w*(?<!_)$
```

in Java or

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?<!_)$
```

in .NET.

**Explanation:**

```
^               # Start of string
[a-zA-Z]        # First character: ASCII letter
[a-zA-Z0-9_]*   # Following characters: ASCII letter, digit or underscore
(?<!_)          # Assert that last character isn't an underscore
$               # End of string
```

See it in action:
[image: Screenshot from RegexBuddy]

Comment: ya i m using C# so let me try it

Comment: @ Tim exp is workign fine now excep the underscore case , i want to allow underscores in between

Comment: By test case I mean an example string that's causing the error message to show. The examples in your question all work as requested.

Comment: i got where the problem is ,my mistake. i m typing abhi_ then it is not alowing me to type if i type abhi and then put underscore between ab_hi then it alows me . so i have to udpate the expression to allow underscores at end actually.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Isn't [a-zA-Z0-9_] = \w in .NET? At least \w includes [a-zA-Z0-9_].

Comment: how to make this expression to allow underscores at any place , u are having amazing tool , thanks

Comment: @Alexey: Yes, but it also includes all other Unicode letters, digits and connecting punctuation. So it also matches `Ä` in .NET, but not in Java.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta: Just remove the `(?<!_)` part. Then it will allow the underscore anywhere except for the start of the string. If you want to allow it there, too, then also remove the `[a-zA-Z]` bit. Also, I advise you to buy [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) if you need to work with regexes. (And I'm not affiliated with that company, just a happy user).